# Why does it take several minutes for my Internet to start working?

Tags: windows, internet-connection

When I first boot up my computer and launch a browser, it takes 5-7 minutes before it will actually load a page. Before then, it just shows the "loading page" screen, no matter how many times I try to refresh (the browser itself doesn't hang, though). This happens when the *computer* is turned on; the router had already been on for several minutes before I turned on the computer. What's the issue?

Comment: What version of windows, what browser, what add-ons/extensions are you using.  If you load a clean copy of WIndows into a Virtual Machine does this still happen.  Does it happen on a Linux installation.  More information is required.

Answer (score 3):

Try this
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools double click SERVICES
go to "Wired AutoConfig" right click Properties and set the "Startup Type: " to "Automatic"

Comment: at the moment this service was set to manual and was turned off. I don't use wireless..

Comment: Its not for wireless! That's why your internet's not working.

Comment: The Wired AutoConfig (DOT3SVC) service is responsible for performing IEEE 802.1X (And that's not wireless :D ) Just turn it on again ;)

Comment: what exactly improves by activating this service?

Comment: If its turned of, you will have problems with your wired connection, wired client must perform an authentication prior to being able to use its switch port. So I recommend you turn it on to Automatic or Manual!

Comment: And don't stop services if you don't know what they do! Also, after doing that restart your PC and see what happens. Also, maybe somethings wrong with IP adresses but I dont know that, it may be milion reasons.

Comment: well, thanks.. now was instantly working... but the first time I restarted and I get into my account it was cleaned up, like a new account, same desktop image but no icons, set for high performance and changed the windows colors.. Now I have the stuff back.. so so strange..

Comment: maybe virus or something... strange!

Comment: never happened since I have win7, maybe the settings changes. Anyway I restated again and was slow again :s

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7686/discussion-between-davidenko-and-totty)

Comment: ok, tomorrow I will talk there, now I have to sleep. see you tomorrow and thanks